# Why does Clang++ compiler fail to compile the following variadic template code?

Tags: c++, c++14, clang++

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>


template<typename... T> struct test {

    using args_type = std::tuple<T...>;

    args_type x;

    template<std::size_t... I>
    void callme(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        int _[] = {(std::get<I>(x).std::tuple_element<I, args_type>::type::~type(), true)...};
    }
};

int main() {
}
```

The error message is

```
clang-3.7  -std=gnu++1y  -Wc++14-extensions test.cpp
test.cpp:15:56: error: expected ')'
        int _[] = {(std::get<I>(x).std::tuple_element<I, args_type>::type::~type(), true)...};
                                                       ^
test.cpp:15:20: note: to match this '('
        int _[] = {(std::get<I>(x).std::tuple_element<I, args_type>::type::~type(), true)...};
                   ^
1 error generated.
```

The same code seems to compile just fine with G++ 4.9.2. I couldn't find any relevant bug report on Clang yet.

Comment: Where did this copy of clang 3.7 come from? The most recent release of LLVM is only 3.6.

Comment: Does it compile with 3.6?

Comment: @Qix nope, it doesn't

Comment: @Qix, it failed to compile in 3.5, 3.6, 3.7-head

Comment: `.std::tuple_element<I, args_type>::type::~type()` is supposed to call the destructor of the element?  How is `::type` not a dependent type there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Appears to be a Clang bug, though the lookup of such pseudo-destructor-names is probably defected and subject of open CWG issues, specifically 555 and 399.

The significant bit of the expansion pattern is

```
std::get<I>(x).std::tuple_element<I, args_type>::type::~type()
```

Here, the bit between `.` and `()` is a *pseudo-destructor-name*; Qualified name lookup then mandates that

> If a *pseudo-destructor-name* (5.2.4) contains a *nested-name-specifier*,
>   the *type-name*s are looked up as types in the scope designated by the
>   *nested-name-specifier*. Similarly, in a *qualified-id* of the form:
>
> *nested-name-specifier<sub>opt</sub>  class-name* `:: ~` *class-name*
>
> the second *class-name* is looked up in the same scope as the first.

I.e. `type` is looked up in  `std::tuple_element<I, args_type>`, where it's found to refer to some type. Note that *class-name* is a grammatical name for identifiers (and *simple-template-id*s), and need not refer to an actual class. `std::get<I>(x).std::tuple_element<I, args_type>::type::~type` then refers to the destructor of `type`.

Workaround with an auxiliary function:

```
template <typename T>
void destroy(T& p) {p.~T();}

template<typename... T> struct test {
    using args_type = std::tuple<T...>;

    args_type x;

    template<std::size_t... I>
    void callme(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        int _[] = {(destroy(std::get<I>(x)), 0)...};
    }
};
```

Comment: I would file a report. That's odd.

Comment: The specification for destructor name lookup is all sorts of messed up. There's at least one longstanding core issue about it.

Comment: @T.C. I just realized how weird this really is.

Comment: @Columbo 399, too. Also, this one is not necessarily a pseudo-destructor. Could be a real one.

Comment: Is the code actually complied with C++14 specification though i.e. it's actually GCC bug? (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf section 5.2.4 page 100)

Comment: @Nat Could you please give the actual paragraph you're referring to?

Comment: The spec on page 97/1206 seems to mention about . and -> but page 100 seems to mention ".", "->" as well as "::"

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, hstong from IBM [mentioned](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23523) a [couple](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/a9zfr8dPCz9CFVrM) [workarounds](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/76Cf7oRFNEjLnr3L) that work better.

```
int _[] = {(std::get<I>(x).::std::tuple_element<I, args_type>::type::~type(), true)...};
```

or

```
int _[] = {(std::get<I>(x).std::template tuple_element<I, args_type>::type::~type(), true)...};
```